# My paper was presented as part of a Keynote speech written by my advisor. What do I mention in my CV?

Tags: conference, cv

I have written a paper jointly with my supervisor. He will be presenting our research as a part of a keynote lecture on an international conference. The lecture is in his name, but a part of that lecture has to do with my research. In fact, he will mention my name on one of the slide as an acknowledgement of my contribution. I am in need of items on my CV for upcoming funding applications and I am wondering **if I should include this lecture on my CV**? If yes, **how can I list this item on my CV**?

Comment: I seemed to have posted this in someone else's name, I would appreciate if someone could merge this question under my account :)

Comment: Since we have, offhand, no way of ascertaining whether these two accounts are indeed the same, I have rejected [this suggested edit](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50302) for the reason that it deviates from the (original) OP's intent. Please feel free to request for account merger and then edit your post yourself if you are indeed the OP.

Comment: Because students usually don't list being mentioned in their advisor's talk on their CV, this would look like you are trying too hard to fill your CV and may do more damage than good. The fact that you did good work will be reflected in your publication of the work and the recommendation letter from your advisor.

Comment: @mich You need to follow [these instructions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts.

Comment: You wouldn't list other papers that referenced yours on your CV, right?  They're not your work, even if they incorporate it.  This is no different.

Answer (score 29):

No, you shouldn't list it on your CV -- it's not your talk. Presumably, this work has or will be published, with you as an author. That, of course, should be on your CV.

Comment: I seemed to have been signed in with someone else's account, so disregard the different names. I did ask him whether I could list it in my CV, and he said yes. Additionally, the lecture uses simulations and graphics I made, as requested by him. Does that affect your opinion?

Comment: No, it still doesn't change my answer. No one ever lists talks that they've contributed material to, but not given, in their CV. Similarly, whenever one sees a talk listed in a CV, the assumption is that the person whose CV it is has given the talk, and it would seem misleading or dishonest if this were not the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Do you think it would be appropriate to list his lecture in a footnote to the (pending) publication entry in my CV (specifically mentioning that it was not given by me, of course)? Or should I simply disregard its existence in its entirety?

Comment: @mich no. The paper is important and should be listed. The fact that someone else mentioned it in some conference is completely irrelevant, adds no value to your CV, and would just make people wonder why you're so desperate you would put it there in the first place.

Comment: @mich: No, don't add a footnote. It's still neither appropriate nor relevant.

Comment: Though definitely remind your advisor to mention this in any recommendation letters you ask him for!

Comment: I agree with Raghu's answer, but not with his comment. It is very common that co-authors of a talk don't actually present anything, or that they're even present at the conference. That doesn't preclude them from including it as a talk (or poster) in their CV.

Comment: @mich To elaborate on appropriateness and relevance: Such a footnote would basically mean "Look, someone was actually interested in this publication!" Think about what that would mean for other items in your CV...

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**
Assuming it was a keynote lecture on a conference that contained some of your data, alongside a whole bunch of other stuff that your professor is working on, it shouldn't go on your CV in any way. An acknowledgement is, unfortunately, not enough to include it on your CV.

**Background**
Journal papers should of course go on a CV when you co-authored. The same goes for Conference Proceedings. International conference abstracts including poster and oral presentations, can (and imho should) be mentioned on a CV when you co-authored, even if you weren't the presenter and even when you weren't even physically there on the conference. You're a co-author and therefore it can be included in your CV (under the header **Conference abstracts**, or **Published Abstracts**, depending on the conference). At least in the STEM disciplines this is commonplace.

If it concerns a keynote lecture at an international conference, and there was a formal abstract submitted including you as a co-author, you can definitely put it on your CV. However, if your professor was invited and did not submit an abstract, I would be very careful adding it as a conference abstract on your CV. If (s)he added you as a co-author on the opening slide, and you participated in the preparation actively, you could consider including it on your CV. If your supervisor wrote the keynote by her- or himself and included some of your data alongside a whole bunch of other stuff, I would not even consider adding it. Then the mention of your name is a sidelong acknowledgement. An acknowledgement is not enough to be mentioned on your CV.

Local, closed departmental, or university meetings generally don't go at your CV as they are considered part of a researcher's normal routines. Personally I even exclude national meetings (I'm based in the Netherlands - a small strip of land which I often refer to as the beach of Germany - explaining why national meetings don't mean much to me).

Down another level - lectures. I'm unsure what you mean with a 'keynote lecture'. When assuming it's a university or college lecture for undergrad students, and not a part of a conference, I wouldn't put it on my CV. The professor who gives the lecture is the one who may put it on her or his CV. **A lecture has no authors** and as such assistants do not take credits directly.

However, all of the above highly depends on your career status. As an undergrad, you may wish to mention as much as possible on your CV. For example, if you haven't got any publication yet on your CV (no poster abstracts, no journal papers *etc*.), you may wish to consider adding things like that 'keynote' lecture on there. In case you do, make a proper heading and summarize what your contribution was. E.g. something like this --

> **Scientific activities**
>   *Applicant assisted in the preparation of a keynote lecture on an international conference.*

A CV is a dynamic abstract of your accomplishments. When those accomplishments are relatively few, you can, and likely should add stuff that more senior scientists will definitely not mention (anymore) on their CVs.

Comment: Thank you for the very insightful answer. The prof's lecture is at an international conference. It goes over his past papers (which I did not author), historically, and then dedicates about a third of it to our latest results, which significantly build on these papers. He will use (not too extensive) simulations that he asked me to write, demonstrating our results.

The reason I am a little "hungry" for CV items is that this is my first publication, and I'd like to apply for a scholarship later this year, so I am trying to see what I can include :-). This is a sticky area, so I am unsure.

Comment: @mich - makes a lot of sense. I've been in that position and probably most up-and-coming researchers have hovered in this area for a while. In my last lines I've proposed an approach you can safely follow. I would recommend *not* to put it under authored papers, but as a separate section like the highlighted text box in the end of my answer. My own CV has a 'teaching Activities' section that contains activities other more senior folks would not even bother to mention. I haven't done much teaching, hence I can't add full-blown courses there.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're a co-author on a talk or poster you will only include it on your CV if you're short of material.  If you're acknowledged in something you don't.

I wouldn't even keep a personal note of it (I wouldn't know if I wasn't there and hadn't provided figures), though I do record talk co-authorships etc. for my own use.

You mention a paper.  Assuming that's going to be published, it's much better than a section of a talk, and there's no doubt that should be on your CV.  If the paper comes up in interview, you can mention that it was an important part of a keynote then, but you might have other good things to say about it instead.